# ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint (have tried everything)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

Having an impossible time finding what this error is.

I use

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

to get this error:

```
2015-12-05 03:20:44 16c8 Error in foreign key constraint of table mydb/enroll:

    FOREIGN KEY (`sectno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`section` (`sectno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
```

So I think it's safe to assume that it's the sectno key and the table it references that is causing me trouble.

So here are my "enroll" tables (the table that it's not letting me create) and the "section" tables

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`section`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`section` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sectno`, `dname`, `cno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_cno_section_idx` (`cno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_pname_section_idx` (`pname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_section`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cno_section`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`course` (`cno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pname_section`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`prof` (`pname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`enroll`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`enroll` (
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `grade` DOUBLE NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`, `dname`, `cno`, `sectno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_dname_enroll_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_cno_enroll_idx` (`cno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_sectno_enroll_idx` (`sectno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cno_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`course` (`cno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sectno_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sectno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`section` (`sectno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm using MySQL workbench forward engineering so I didn't actually type out the code myself. I've checked and double checked and triple checked and all the data types seem to match, so it must be this error that is the problem: "Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns." I'm not entirely sure I understood it 100%, but I thought it meant that they FK being referenced must be in the first column of the referenced table. So in the section table, I like..declared

```
 `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',`
```

before all the other columns so that it was "first," and still nothing. I've spent hour after hour after hour and I am just...mentally exhausted. Somebody please help

Edit: here are the rest of the tables:

-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`student`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`student` (
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sname` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `sex` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT '',
  `age` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `year` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `gpa` DOUBLE NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`dept`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`dept` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `numphds` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`prof`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`prof` (
  `pname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pname`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_dname_prof_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_prof`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`course`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`course` (
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cname` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cno`, `dname`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `pk_dname_course_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `pk_dname_course`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`major`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`major` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname`, `sid`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_sid_major_idx` (`sid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_major`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid_major`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: can you clear up, is this during the create of the tables, or using them

Comment: creation. I actually had already created the section table. It is in the creation of the enroll table that I'm having difficulty. The whole project is about 7 table, which I used workbench to forward engineer using all the diagrams, and it was the enroll table giving me trouble. This time I created each table one by one (instead of all at once like I had tried previously) and eroll is once again the problem table

Comment: you aren't showing us 3 out of the other 4 tables we need to see

Comment: because I know that the following runs fine, having pruned out what you haven't shown us ----> http://pastie.org/10610406

Comment: I have added the rest of the tables! I only showed the section one because that was the one singled out by the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script runs all the way thru. If it does not, change the 2 lines at the top to a different schema name, and run it without any `comment` sections active.

I cannot find a reference at the moment for that reason, but I stumbled into it once here.

To be clear on that, in some interfaces, a `comment` section would throw an error.

Needless to say, the order in which they run is important.

All of your FK conditions look good. The datatypes and signs are good and match from *referencing* to *referenced* tables. And in the *referenced* tables, they all have left-most indexes on those columns.

```
create schema asdf789;

use asdf789;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `section` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sectno`, `dname`, `cno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_cno_section_idx` (`cno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_pname_section_idx` (`pname` ASC)  COMMENT ''
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sname` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `sex` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT '',
  `age` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `year` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `gpa` DOUBLE NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`dept`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `numphds` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`prof`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prof` (
  `pname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pname`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_dname_prof_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_prof`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`course`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cname` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cno`, `dname`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `pk_dname_course_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `pk_dname_course`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`major`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `major` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname`, `sid`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_sid_major_idx` (`sid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_major`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid_major`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
    REFERENCES `student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enroll` (
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `grade` DOUBLE NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`, `dname`, `cno`, `sectno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_dname_enroll_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_cno_enroll_idx` (`cno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_sectno_enroll_idx` (`sectno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
    REFERENCES `student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dname_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cno_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cno`)
    REFERENCES `course` (`cno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sectno_enroll`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sectno`)
    REFERENCES `section` (`sectno`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! But what exactly did you change from my code?

Comment: well I got fragments from you, but ordered them so they would succeed. Perhaps. I also took out the reference to the database name outside of the first 2 lines. So maybe it was a db name issue

Comment: Ah yes, I see you put section at the top. Well, it worked so that's good enough for me, thanks again